How to make SSL Certs more efficiently in AWS
I deployed an node.js website in AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. I need to be able to make lots of domains for my site easily. However, it took me a while just to get one working because I had to create an EC2 instance, install certbot, make a cert, then copy that cert over to the certificate manager. Is there any way to automate this/do it faster? I used to use vercel and I could just type a hostname in and it would generate a SSL cert automatically.

Are all the sites in one domain? a1.domain.tld, a2.domain.tld, etc?

no they are different domains

https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/ plus some automation.

Use AWS Certificate Manager (free), and build some automation if desired.
ACM can only share certificates with AWS managed services, such as an application load balancer, you can't install them directly on EC2. If you must have your certs on EC2 rather than an ALB you'll have to build some kind of automation yourself.

the dns website I use does not support CNAME, which AWS requires to verify domains. Are there any other options?

What do you mean "The DNS website I use does not support CNAME"? Are you saying your DNS host doesn't let you create CNAME records? If that's so you need to change DNS hosts. Noting that DNS registrar can be different from the DNS host.

yeah that’s what i’m saying. I use freedns. it’s a website that has thousands of domains that you can use for a free subdomain. I haven’t been able to fine any others like that.

You should register yourself your own domain. There are plenty of registrars, AWS, CloudFlare, etc. CloudFlare does free DNS hosting, AWS is from memory $0.50 per domain per month. Otherwise if you want to stay with a non-standard DNS system you're going to have to find a workaround.
